# OLE Automation: IDispatch implementing class; client or Server?

Tags: com, visual-c++, ole

I have a project which I'm studying the codebase of, however I'm trying to understand how this whole OLE Automation works.

In the OLE Automation protocol, which application has to implement IDispatch on one of its classes, the server or the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server implements IDispatch, the client uses it to make the calls.  The terms "OLE" and "ActiveX" have fallen out of favor, it is all "COM" now.  The technology is however exactly the same.